# Can Android or iOS applications determine if their host device is configured by a Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, mdm

I am working on a mobile application and would like to inform users when an update is available, if that user's device is not managed by an MDM. If the device *is* MDM-configured, we don't expect the end user will be able to update the app without the configuration being changed by the administrator. To provide a better user experience, we want to provide relevant information. To do this, I'd like ideas to determine if an app (written in Kotlin/Swift) can poll for this type of information.

I saw some things in the Android Docs about checking for Restrictions Providers, but I think this is the wrong avenue. I'm not very familiar with this, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: On iOS you cannot query the device for managed state. The MDM can deploy [configuration data](https://www.appconfig.org/) to an app so you could send a flag to disable the update notification. However, if the app is from the App Store (even if it is delivered as part of an MDM policy) then updates are delivered exactly as they are on an unmanaged device; the user can opt for automatic updates or update manually

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, my team does not always control the MDM, so deploying config data isn't a great option. We find that some organizations that configure an MDM to deploy our app, seem to do so in such a way that prevents users from getting automatic updates. There are too many MDMs out there to be able to understand how they all differ, and reaching some of these companies' MDM admins (and getting them to care enough to update) can be difficult. Still, I think my best option may be to improve our lines of communication to the MDM admins.

Comment: Yes. The app config approach is a standard that should be supported by all MDMs (at least all of the major ones). You can then document the process to allow admins to disable the update prompt if they want to. You should probably only alert the user to an upgrade once and/or provide a "don't tell me again" button on the notification so that users won't be pestered continually.